# How adaptible are the C and C++ standards to a hypothetical ternary hardware architecture?

Tags: c++, c, architecture, standards, hardware

How easily could you program a ternary computer in C or C++?

Obviously, the standard logical operators (like `&`, `|` and `^`) only make sense when using binary logic.

For integer values, the C standard refers to value ranges while the C++ standard mentions bit lengths (eg. long has to be at least 32bit long). How would that apply to a computer using trits (i.e. ternary bits) ?

Would it, in general, be practical to use a slightly modified version of C/C++ for programming on a ternary architecture, or should you design a new programming language from scratch?

Important points to consider would be backward compatibility (could binary-assuming programs be easily compiled for a ternary architecture, or would an emulation of binary data storage be necessary?) and assumptions implicit in the design of the C/C++ standards.

Comment: If you look closely at the standards, you'll see that they generally describe expected observable behaviour.   They don't mandate a binary host system.   And, BTW, the type of computer you are describing is *ternary*, not trinary.

Comment: I've seen both trinary and ternary used, but ternary does seems to be far more common. I've edited the question.

Comment: Looking at [Signed integers are 2s complement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html), I suspect they assume binary observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The wording of the C++ standard assumes a binary architecture:

> **[intro.memory]/1:**
>
> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A
> byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
> execution character set and the eight-bit code units of the
> Unicode UTF-8 encoding form **and is composed of a contiguous sequence
> of bits**, the number of which is implementation-defined.
>
> **[basic/fundamental]/4:**
>
> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2 [raised
> to the power of] n where n is the number of bits in the value
> representation of that particular size of integer.

Furthermore, *bit-fields* and *padding bits* are frequently used concepts.

Operators like left-shift, right-shift are also referring to bits, and bitwise-and, bitwise-or and bitwise-xor are by definition operation that operate at bit level asuming that each bit is either true or false.

#### What if the standard would be adapted to ternary architecture ?

We could imagine that the standard could use another term to designate the smallest piece of information in the architecture, in a similar way than it was done for the *byte* (the byte although most often 8 bits is not defined as such in the standard, so that the standard could well work with machines having 10 bit bytes).

Nevertheless the consequences would be terrible:

- left-shift for example is assumed in many algorithms to multiply by a power of 2, and suddenly, it would multiply  by a power of 3.  Same for right-shift.  So a lot of existing code would not work anymore.
- bitwise operations are not defined for trits:  they are only defined for binary bits.  So the standard would have to redefine them in a way or another (for example by emulating the original behavior with some kind of power of 2 maths).  Again, their are chances that some existing code gets broken, esepecially if used in combination with shifts.

#### *Additional remark*

Since the visionary book "*Cybernetics*" of Norbert Wiener published in 1948 (!!!) it makes no doubt anymore that alternatives to the binary sytems are nout.  In the chapter "*Computing machines and the nervous system*" he explained very well why numerical machines are more accurate and performant than analog ones, and that among the numerical machines, the binary arithmetic outperformed the others because it was simpler, faster and in addition [easier and cheaper to implement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware#Digital_computation).  For the time being, nobody achieved to demonstrate the contrary, so no ternary computer architecture in sight soon.

#### *Comments*

*Peter points out in the comments that the implementation just has to offer the specified behavior of the abstract machine defined in the C++ standard.  This is true according to [intro.abstract]/5.  But my point is that this is only a theoretical truth in view of ternary machines.*

*The binary model is such a strong assumption in so many places of the standard, and intertwined with the addressing scheme, that I will pretend that it is impossible to emulate in an efficient and consistent manner on a ternary machine.*

*Just to illustrate the issue with the definition of bytes:  it requires 6 trits to fit the requirements for a byte.  However 6 trits corresponds to 9,5 bits.  In order for a byte to correspond to a consecutive number of bits as required by the standard you'd need it to be s trits so that pow(3,s) == pow(2,n). This equation has no solutions.  Alternatively you could say that a byte is 9 bits stored into 6 trits and that you just ignore some ternary values. But as bytes are used to store pointers, you'd also ignore some memory ranges. So you'd need a mapping function to convert between values stored in bytes and machine addresses.  But what then with hardware alignment constraints ? These might not correspond to alignments that can be expressed according to the binary model, etc...  In the end you would need to have a slow virtual machine that completely emulates by software a binary architecture (certainly with the same level of performance than the many MIPS emulators on the x86 architecture, so ok for educational purpose).  I think that this could then comply with the standard, but no longer our performance expectations.*

Comment: No, the C++ standard does not require a binary architecture.   It requires that an implementation sets things up so that, to a running program, the behaviour is consistent with requirements the standard.   How that behaviour is achieved is up to the implementation.    BTW:  a ternary electronic computer existed in 1958.

Comment: @Peter I understand what you say.  I've edited my answer with an additional comment to explain more in depth what I mean with "assumes binary" and why it is not easy to run C++ on a ternary computer with the current definition of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Louis-Dr ternary Verilog on GitHub.  The problem is that C makes too many assumptions that need to be backed up or redefined to make more specific use of the language. He defines binary as a basic signal that can carry 0 or 1 (bit) and ternary as a signal that can carry -1, 0, or +1 (trit). Thus a byte would be binary[8] and a triad (of trits) would be ternary[3]. The decision ? would be a?b:c:d.
Operators and shifts would work in respect to what was being shifted. A trit wise logic operations can be defined by its k-map for its name. This would be consistent with programming something like the 3niti.org assembly language.  If you are thinking in ternary, this all starts to make sense. A number value is a number for conversion of values back and forth either binary or balanced ternary. I would use a slightly modified representation for the heptiventimal representation for triads starting at -13=G thus G H K M N P R T V W X Y Z  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D not stepping on (redefining) any hex or octals and consistent with Setsun nonary (2 trit subordinate) definition.